# Исключения и зачем они нужны?

Tags: java, c++, try, catch

Объясните мне,  пожалуйста, как начинающему программисту, зачем нужны исключения? try catch вот это всё. Они нужны только для поиска ошибок в коде и их исправления? Исключения не идут в релизную версию программы? Или идут и зачем и как они там работают тогда?

Comment: Если коротко, нет, исключения нужны не только для исправления ошибок. Бывают исключения неправильного использования (передали `null` куда не нужно), которые можно исправить, бывают ситуативные, которые предсказать и исправить нельзя (сервер недоступен, файл занят другим процессом, пользователь ввел не те данные). Исключения помогают обнаруживать и обрабатывать такие ситуации (пнуть пользователя проверить ввод или повторить попытку позже), вместо того, чтобы ронять всю программу с ошибкой. Они идут в релизную версию и зачастую являются единственным способом понять, что пошло не так, по логам.

Comment: @aa_talanin а чего не ответом?

Comment: А почему не просто посмотреть [эти вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)? Уже столько раз разбиралось...

Comment: Не для поиска ошибок программистом, а программой для реагирования на ошибки.

Comment: исключения дают повышение скорости программы. Так как они происходят реже, чем как обычно, то ручные проверки флагов сильно тормозят и портят весь код. Исключения автоматически выходят из функций, циклов сами, а программист только в одном месте их отслеживает и делает дальнейшие действия для этих исключений.